Why am I having CDS API format error after CDS BETA?
[for context I am using mac OS and Python]
After installing cds api, and basically following the instructions from the official website's user guide for cds api setup here: https://cds-beta.climate.copernicus.eu/how-to-api, and running this sample code for data access, this error is being returned
{Sample code}
import cdsapi
client = cdsapi.Client()

dataset = "reanalysis-era5-pressure-levels"
request = {
    'product_type': 'reanalysis',
    'format': 'grib',  # 'netcdf' can also be used
    'variable': 'temperature',
    'pressure_level': '850',
    'year': '2020',
    'month': '01',
    'day': '01',
    'time': '00:00',
    'area': [50, -130, 20, -60],  # North, West, South, East (example area)
}

client.retrieve(dataset, request, 'downloaded_file.grib')

{Error}

AssertionError: The cdsapi key provided is not the correct format,
please ensure it conforms to: <UID>:<APIKEY>

However, after following the necessary action to avoid that error (which includes the addtion of UID), the same error will then pop out.
Any thing that I did missed?
I tried both removing UID since the new update instructed that it is no longer needed to be practiced (as mentioned in the user guide), and also adding UID still since I am getting the same error message of

AssertionError: The cdsapi key provided is not the correct format,
please ensure it conforms to: <UID>:<APIKEY>


I had the same problem, but was quickly fixed after upgrading the cdsapi package: pip install --upgrade cdsapi
Note the .cdsapi file is in the form:
url: https://cds-beta.climate.copernicus.eu/api
key: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
You can copy and paste the above from here: https://cds-beta.climate.copernicus.eu/how-to-api. Or alternativly find your new key under, "Your Profile" then "Personal Access Token."
